# I can't deploy my node js application to Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, canvas, github-actions

I was trying to deploy my website to Microsoft Azure Linux App Service with Github actions. In glitch, project is perfectly working but in azure gives error

I don't have canvas in my package.json and I don't use it but azure seems try to install that. Can you help? Here is the logs:

```
2020-08-09T10:17:31.9162150Z > canvas@1.6.13 install /home/runner/work/UNITE/UNITE/node_modules/canvas
2020-08-09T10:17:31.9202046Z > node-gyp rebuild
2020-08-09T10:17:31.9202737Z 
2020-08-09T10:17:34.0385309Z make: Entering directory '/home/runner/work/UNITE/UNITE/node_modules/canvas/build'
2020-08-09T10:17:34.0426950Z   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
2020-08-09T10:17:34.0973375Z   COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
2020-08-09T10:17:34.1069049Z   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4454935Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4468582Z ../src/JPEGStream.h: In function ‘boolean empty_closure_output_buffer(j_compress_ptr)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4486281Z ../src/JPEGStream.h:42:108: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4504659Z    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4522442Z                                                                                                             ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4523871Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4524808Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4525632Z ../../nan/nan.h:1026:46: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4526405Z    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4527132Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4528183Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4529827Z ../src/JPEGStream.h: In function ‘void term_closure_destination(j_compress_ptr)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4532207Z ../src/JPEGStream.h:63:113: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4533900Z    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, data_argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4534837Z                                                                                                                  ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4535600Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4536313Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4537052Z ../../nan/nan.h:1026:46: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4537744Z    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4538864Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4539586Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:20:0:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4541835Z ../src/JPEGStream.h:71:112: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4543438Z    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)dest->closure->fn, 2, end_argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4544561Z                                                                                                                 ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4545341Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4546040Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4546761Z ../../nan/nan.h:1026:46: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4547439Z    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4548171Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4549566Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static void Canvas::Initialize(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4553387Z ../src/Canvas.cc:60:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4554026Z    Nan::Set(target, Nan::New("Canvas").ToLocalChecked(), ctor->GetFunction());
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4554314Z                                                                            ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4554634Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4554860Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4555923Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:6126:46: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction(v8::Local<v8::Context>)
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4556178Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4556417Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4557087Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:6126:46: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4557986Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::New(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4558924Z ../src/Canvas.cc:74:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4559347Z    if (info[0]->IsNumber()) width = info[0]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4559731Z                                                          ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4560077Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4560285Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4561219Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4561457Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4561688Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4562250Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4562969Z ../src/Canvas.cc:75:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4563350Z    if (info[1]->IsNumber()) height = info[1]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4563581Z                                                           ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4563817Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4564025Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4564940Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4565170Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4565380Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4566113Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4566929Z ../src/Canvas.cc:76:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4567598Z    if (info[2]->IsString()) type = !strcmp("pdf", *String::Utf8Value(info[2]))
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4567861Z                                                                             ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4568090Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4568392Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4569267Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:3135:5: note: candidate: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4569519Z      Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local<v8::Value> obj);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4569675Z      ^~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4570216Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:3135:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4571008Z ../src/Canvas.cc:78:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4571244Z      : !strcmp("svg", *String::Utf8Value(info[2]))
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4571456Z                                                 ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4571679Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4571883Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4572759Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:3135:5: note: candidate: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4572983Z      Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local<v8::Value> obj);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4573121Z      ^~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4573595Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:3135:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4574380Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_SETTER_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::SetWidth(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, Nan::NAN_SETTER_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4574995Z ../src/Canvas.cc:119:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4575298Z      canvas->width = value->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4575477Z                                         ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4575664Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4575858Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4576644Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4576848Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4577034Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4577516Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4578297Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_SETTER_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::SetHeight(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, Nan::NAN_SETTER_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4578900Z ../src/Canvas.cc:140:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4579203Z      canvas->height = value->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4579379Z                                          ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4579566Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4579760Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4580505Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4580705Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4580892Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4581474Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4582068Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static void Canvas::ToBufferAsyncAfter(uv_work_t*)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4582777Z ../src/Canvas.cc:221:31: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4583076Z      closure->pfn->Call(1, argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4583239Z                                ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4583492Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4583680Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4583872Z ../../nan/nan.h:1742:3: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4584053Z    Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4584185Z    ^~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4584880Z ../src/Canvas.cc:226:31: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4585214Z      closure->pfn->Call(2, argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4585374Z                                ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4585564Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4585744Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4585931Z ../../nan/nan.h:1742:3: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4586112Z    Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4586240Z    ^~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4586882Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::ToBuffer(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4587484Z ../src/Canvas.cc:274:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4587812Z            compression_level = info[1]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4588004Z                                                     ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4588195Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4588410Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4589157Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4589354Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4589539Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4590018Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4590620Z ../src/Canvas.cc:279:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4590955Z              uint32_t tmp = info[1]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4591143Z                                                  ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4591335Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4591514Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4592261Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4592461Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4592647Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4593124Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4593713Z ../src/Canvas.cc:301:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4594028Z          filter = info[2]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4594203Z                                        ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4594391Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4594570Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4595334Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4595594Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4595779Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4596262Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4596933Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In function ‘cairo_status_t streamPNG(void*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4597903Z ../src/Canvas.cc:377:102: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4640957Z    Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)closure->fn, 3, argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4641326Z                                                                                                       ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4641597Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4641847Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4642084Z ../../nan/nan.h:1026:46: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4642323Z    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4642560Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4643438Z ../src/Canvas.cc: In static member function ‘static Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Canvas::StreamPNGSync(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4644198Z ../src/Canvas.cc:396:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4644614Z            compression_level = info[1]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4644850Z                                                     ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4645088Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4645309Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4646234Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4646500Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4646726Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4647319Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4648055Z ../src/Canvas.cc:401:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4648462Z              uint32_t tmp = info[1]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4648701Z                                                  ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4648937Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4649156Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4650073Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4650328Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4650555Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4651143Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4651969Z ../src/Canvas.cc:423:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Uint32Value()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4652317Z          filter = info[2]->Uint32Value();
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4652515Z                                        ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4652737Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4652940Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4653786Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note: candidate: v8::Maybe<unsigned int> v8::Value::Uint32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4654018Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4654227Z                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4654964Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2707:41: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4655886Z ../src/Canvas.cc:446:103: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4656494Z      Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), (v8::Local<v8::Function>)closure.fn, 1, argv);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4656893Z                                                                                                        ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4683530Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:22:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4683765Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4683989Z ../../nan/nan.h:1026:46: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4684215Z    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value> MakeCallback(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4684440Z                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4685571Z ../src/Canvas.cc:452:103: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4717590Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4718089Z In file included from /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4718529Z                  from /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:27,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4718724Z                  from ../src/Canvas.h:11,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4719012Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4719721Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note: candidate: v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Isolate*) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4772536Z                  Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4772780Z                                ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4773582Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4773819Z    declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4773983Z    ^~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4774575Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2686:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4774860Z                  Local<Object> ToObject(Isolate* isolate) const);
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4775061Z                                ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4775646Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4775878Z    declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4776040Z    ^~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4776958Z ../src/Canvas.cc:655:73: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’ is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4777569Z        context = canvas->Get(Nan::New<String>("context").ToLocalChecked());
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4777845Z                                                                          ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4778375Z In file included from /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8-internal.h:14:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4778863Z                  from /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:27,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4779232Z                  from ../src/Canvas.h:11,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4779431Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4779947Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:3553:51: note: declared here
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4780193Z    V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", Local<Value> Get(Local<Value> key));
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4780434Z                                                    ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4781091Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4781325Z    declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4781487Z    ^~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4782206Z ../src/Canvas.cc:657:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::ToObject()’
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4782837Z          Context2d *context2d = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Context2d>(context->ToObject());
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4783133Z                                                                                      ^
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4783388Z In file included from ../src/Canvas.h:11:0,
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4783606Z                  from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4784771Z /home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/v8.h:2672:44: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Value::ToObject(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4785021Z    V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Object> ToObject(
2020-08-09T10:17:35.4785250Z                                             ^~~~~~~~
2020-08-09T10:17:35.5490609Z 
home/runner/work/UNITE/UNITE/node_modules/canvas
2020-08-09T10:17:35.5490609Z gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
2020-08-09T10:17:35.5491022Z gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
2020-08-09T10:17:35.5491278Z gyp ERR! not ok 
2020-08-09T10:17:35.7641923Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8416156Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8417216Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/external-ip/node_modules/fsevents):
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8417667Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8417824Z 
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8417996Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8418162Z npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8418555Z npm ERR! canvas@1.6.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8418736Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8418889Z npm ERR! 
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8419113Z npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.6.13 install script.
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8419427Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8447875Z 
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8448259Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8449274Z npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-08-09T10_17_35_838Z-debug.log
2020-08-09T10:17:35.8630218Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

mine suggestion to you is install visual studio code. Then add Azure App service extension to it.
Open the node application folder.
Run npm install command.
then run your app with npm run dev.
Once it is running fine you can deploy it to azure.
Her is a detailed article if you need some help. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01?tabs=bash)

Comment: I am not just one person at this project so I can't use visual studio code to deploy. We have to use github.

Comment: So it is running on local pc or not before u deploy ?